# Using JTA with Hibernate native API (without JPA)

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, ejb, jta

I am trying to use JTA to manage transactions in my EJB but I want to use Hibernate native API, not JPA (so using Hibernate sessions etc.).

Problem is that when I call EJB method annotated with `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)`, transaction does not begin or commit and I just get `java.sql.SQLException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction` on insert (save) after some time. The transaction itself is created but not active.

This is my hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.datasource">jdbc/dataSource</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">cz.app.custom.hibernate.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">jta</property>
    <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform">org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.SunOneJtaPlatform</property>
    <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.CMTTransactionFactory</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="format_sql">true</property>

    <!-- Mappings -->
    <mapping resource="model/Email.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

My EJB:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
public class MailService {

    public void send(Email email) {
        ... // Do some mail sending
        persist(Email email);
    }

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    private void persist(Email email) {

        // Persist
        System.out.println("CURRENT TRX: " + HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().getTransaction()); // This prints out non-null value, so there is some transaction
        DaoFactory.obtain(Email.class).insert(email);
    }
}
```

**Where is the problem? What am I missing?**

AS GlassFish 4

Hibernate 4

Java EE 7

Comment: what is your persistence.xml file?

Comment: I had no persistence.xml when posting this question, but anyway, when I added persistence.xml the result was the same. Later, I just forgot about JTA and started using custom transaction interceptor...

Comment: what are the contents of persistence.xml?